# Firebase as backend for chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add chat between users in my android app.

I read about [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) and I understand that I [must implement an app server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) (backend) apart from Firebase.

On the other hand, I found some sources using another method: they use Firebase Realtime Database itself as a backend (e.g [MChat-master](https://github.com/XYZ123iiitm/MChat-master)). And looking through the code it seems that `FirebaseMessaging` is not used at all. They send chat messages to Firebase and listen for changes in the data. When a message is uploaded to the server the data is changed, the listener is invoked and they pull the message on the receiving phone.

My question is: which way is preferred?

The first method sounds more authentic to me, and the second one looks like a workaround for not having to deal with a backend server.

**First Method (using FCM)**:

**Advantages:**

- Use a service and a broadcast receiver in client (easy frontend)
- The messages are sent to the client and they will be received whenever the app is up (no worries about messages being delivered when the app is closed)

**Disadvantages:**

- Have to implement backend

**Second Method (using Firebase as a backend):**

**Advantages:**

- Not having to deal with a backend server
- I'm already using Firebase Realtime Database so I'm familiar with its queries

**Disadvantages:**

- Will have to add listeners in my all activites to listen for data changes on the server and decide whether to pull the new message
- I don't see an easy way of handling incoming messages when the app is not running (the listeners are not awake)

So is using Firebase as a backend for chat a standard way? If so, what's your take on the disadvatanges I've listed?

Comment: how about keeping an firebase listener always awake for listening the changes/receiving new messages inside a service will be never be killed by android OS, also you can keep it inside BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: I'd say this is about a bit opinion based and *probably* will be closed as opinion-based. Not sure about it though, you are giving good info.

Comment: This question is most likely opinion based, so here is my opinion: Do both... have a server that holds the REST messages, in a way that you have a certified repository of the data, also have a localized (internal to that device), so that you can "realtime" the messages... If the message is received "online", then you can use the local, and once a device starts/stops your applicaton, you syncronize the data. Also, as far as "data security" goes, having a `php` script somewhere, that sends encrypted text/json, is mostly enough. No need for a specific Android project.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, there is not a standard way to build chat modules (or anything else really), but rather efficient methods to implement your particular feature set..

In this case, I would say that it depends on if you want to notify your users about incoming messages outside the app or not ... If you don't, than there should not be any problem using Firebase w/o a backend service and just listen for changes..

However, if you do need a notification about new messages even when the app is not running then pure change-based listening is not optimal solution.. You should be able to setup a service that would try to listen for changes when the app is out as well.. But Google (and Apple for that matter) have ***highly*** optimized processes for handling push notifications which do not turn on the antenna furiously and are saving up precious battery life and other resources ...

Despite all of this, developing it w/o backend will be surely less costly and if your goal is to make an MVP or a prototype as fast as possible, than pre-mature optimizing will do more harm than good ...

All things considered, don't look for a standard way.. ***There isn't one*** ... Sort out your priorities and features that your solution needs to have and the capacity/cost you want to invest, then make your decision ..